# Sum of integers in a list in Python - def Recursive_function(one-argument)

Tags: python, list, function, recursion, sum

Sum of the elements (representing integers) in a list. 
For ex. `A = ["xx", "3e", "5", "44"]`

My function returns `49`. So, the ***RECURSIVE*** one should do the same.

I implemented the ***ITERATIVE*** version successfully.

```py
def add_iter(my_list):
    t = 0
    for x in my_list:
        if x.isdigit() == True:
            t+= int(x)
    print(t)
```

I would like to convert it to ***RECURSIVE*** function.

Comment: Hello, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: Where does that `a` come from, in your `for` statement?

Comment: I have been pushing to think a solution without defining new variables... 
# scan all elements, remove non-integers, return sum...

Makes no sense to define new variables in the function and do the recursion. Confused here. @JosephBudin

Comment: "a" was a list to test. a = ["aa", "a3", "33", "5"] for example... It works successfully when I call **add_iter(a)**

Comment: So why you give your function `add_iter` a parameter `my_list`? Inside your function you should work with that, instead of the variable defined outside the function (`A`)

Comment: It was a mistake. Thank you. Just replaced [a] to [my_list] @SimonFink

Answer (score 2):

Since it's an exercise, i'm not writing the answer, but giving some hints

- The sum of an empty list is zero
- the sum of a non-empty list is (the first element) + (sum of the rest of the list)
- the first element might be ignored if it's not a number

Answer (score 0):

The recursive version functions similarly where you only *iterate* through each element before recursing to the remainder of the list. Your base case would be when the list only has one element left. I would suggest making a helper class to ensure that your values are valid *numbers*

```
# Helper function to clean up int value
def zero_or_value(value):
  try:
    return int(value)
  except ValueError as err:
    # Handler err here if you want
    pass
  return 0


def recursive_add_iter(my_list):
  if not my_list: # Return 0 if list is empty
    return 0
  elif len(my_list) == 1: # Base case, try converting last element
    return zero_or_value(my_list[0])

  return zero_or_value(my_list[0]) + recursive_add_iter(my_list[1:])


A = ["xx", "3e", "5", "44"]

print(recursive_add_iter(A))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def add_recursive(my_list):
    if my_list:
        x = my_list[0]
        if x.isdigit():
            return int(x) + add_recursive(my_list[1:])
        else:
            return add_recursive(my_list[1:])
    else:
        return 0


A = ["xx", "3e", "5", "44"]
add_recursive(A)
# 49
```

Answer (score 0):

Shorter recursive solution:

```
def add_iter(d):
  return (0 if not d[0].isdigit() else int(d[0]))+(0 if not d[1:] else add_iter(d[1:]))

A = ["xx", "3e", "5", "44"]
print(add_iter(A))
```

Output:

```
49
```